# Cannot copy file from local machine to AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In my Amazon EC2 instance, my application is located at `/usr/local/apps/[my_app]`. My problem is that I cannot transfer my file from local machine to the remote server. Supposed on my local path directory, I have a file named "dog.txt". On sftp connection with my Amazon EC2 instance, I can `put dog.txt` successfully; however, when I jump into `/usr` folder, I cannot even `put dog.txt` anymore. It said that

`Uploading dog.txt to /usr/dog/txt`

`remote open("/usr/dog.txt"): Permission denied`

Please help

Comment: Have you checked which user are you using to copy the file from SFTP and what user you log into EC2? If they are different, try giving required permissions so that other users can R/W it.

Comment: Thank you :), I forgot to add permissions thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has nothing to do with AWS or EC2. It is a simple UNIX concept. To explain this in a simple way, just sftp all your files first to `/tmp` on remote server.

in order to solve your problem execute this command 
`$ chmod 777 -R /usr/local/apps/[my_app]`

After this command is executed, you can copy files directly from your local machine or from `/tmp`.

Comment: Wow, that solves my problem. Now, I can transfer files between my machine and my server. Thank you !!